# Solve System Using Gaussian Elimination. Answer in Vector Form.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a system using Gaussian Elimination to get to  RE form (the one where the leading numbers are not reduced to one's) and then back substituting. However, I got the wrong answer can someone point out where I went wrong?

My work:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-3&-2&0\\
        -1&2&1&0\\
        2&4&6&0\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

R2 = R2 + R1

R3 = R3 - 2R1

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-3&-2&0\\
        0&-1&-1&0\\
        0&10&10&0\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

R3 = R3 + 10R2

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-3&-2&0\\
        0&-1&-1&0\\
        0&0&0&0\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$-y - t = 0 $

-> $ y = -t$

$x - 3y - 2t=0$

-> $x - 3(-t) -2t = 0 $

-> $x = -t $

My answer:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        -1\\
        -1\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

The correct answer:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        1\\
        1\\
       -1
      \end{array}
    \right]t$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that $t$ represents the third component of the vector. This means your answer should be $[x,y, z] = [-t, -t, t]$, which is equivalent to the answer given (since $t$ is an arbitrary real number).